# SXA autosuggest results sorting

Tags: sxa, content-search

I'm using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8, this the configuration of the SXA suggester :

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">sxaSuggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">BlendedInfixLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="contextField">_language</str>
<str name="field">suggestionadge_s</str>
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_suggester</str>
<str name="payloadField">templatedisplaynameadge_s</str>
<str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
</lst>
</searchComponent>
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy" >
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="suggest.dictionary">sxaSuggester</str>
<str name="suggest">true</str>
<str name="suggest.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
<str name="suggest.count">30</str>
<str name="suggest.collate">true</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
<str>suggest</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```

As I'm using **BlendedInfixLookupFactory** it should sort the results according to which item that has the searched query closer to the start of the suggestion.

But this is not the case as the below screenshot:
[image]

As the **News Item 1** should be the first one.

Comment: Are you using Solr 7.2.1? Try to set also <str name="weightField">$fieldname$</str> which I think you are missing based on this https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/suggester.html#context-filtering

Comment: Yes. I'm using Solr 7.2.1, Which field should I use at $fieldname$,suggestionadge_s field which I use at : 
<str name="field">suggestionadge_s</str>

Comment: Seems `suggestionadge_s` makes sense for your setup

Comment: Please always check suggestions also in the Solr admin panel (you can use admin panel to make a suggestion request). Check what is returned there because I'm pretty sure that you will see the same results there.